# How To reduce matches in OpenCV pattern recognition?

Tags: android, opencv

[image]

Hi I m developing android application which recognize pattern, It si working as you can see but I have to face with the problem of over matching.I have read that it is caused because my matcher is too sensitive.For matching I use this kind of matcher:

```
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
```

...

```
matcher.match(descriptor1, descriptorLogo, matches);
```

I also try to implement `knnmatch()` but it's reault I can not draw out with the function `Features2d.drawMatches()`

Thanks for any answer hopely it will solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in the matches vector, every match has a confidence measure. You can select only those with higer confidence.

Second approach, which will give you also a good performance boost, is to select fewer keypoints by tuning the keypoint extraction algorithm. Read about your descriptor of choice, and see how the input parameters influence the number of selected points. Set those parameters in the constructor. You have to test it a lot, and check that the quality of the final result it not degraded.

Comment: Thanks it is a good answer, I have voted it up but I will wait a bit with accept, for more answers, but thanks men

Comment: By the way, it seems you're using the code on android. Did you try the new ORB descriptor? it's very fast. And the latest (from trunk) seems to be improved.

Comment: Yeah I m using ORB detector BRIEF descriptor and BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING matcher

Comment: Can I ask U how and wath can I change in descriptor init?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know. But you can read more here http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf about ORB. And my guess is that they use some adaptive parameters to always have around 400 keypoints. If that's true, your job is a bit more complicated.

Comment: And maybe you have to ask them the permission to use the paper. I am not sure if it's meant to be public

Answer (score 5):

There are several techiniques for removing outliers or refining matches:

- Cross check
- Ratio test
- RANSAC+Homography for planar shapes

I usually apply the last two ones.

RATIO TEST:

```
BFMatchermatcher(CV_L2);
vector<vector<DMatch>>nearest_neighbors;
matcher.radiusMatch(
right_points_to_find_flat,
right_features_flat,
nearest_neighbors,
2.0f);

// Check that the found neighbors are unique (throw away neighbors
//  that are too close together, as they may be confusing)
std::set<int>found_in_right_points; // for duplicate prevention
for(inti=0;i<nearest_neighbors.size();i++) {
DMatch _m;
if(nearest_neighbors[i].size()==1) {
    _m = nearest_neighbors[i][0]; // only one neighbor
} else if(nearest_neighbors[i].size()>1) {
        // 2 neighbors – check how close they are
        double ratio = nearest_neighbors[i][0].distance / nearest_neighbors[i][1].distance;
if(ratio < 0.7) { // not too close
    // take the closest (first) one
    _m = nearest_neighbors[i][0];
} else { // too close – we cannot tell which is better
        continue; // did not pass ratio test – throw away
}
} else {
        continue; // no neighbors... :(
}
```

RANSAC+Homography:

```
std::vector<Point2f> object;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    object.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }
  Mat H = findHomography( object, scene, CV_RANSAC, status );

  //draw only the matches considered inliers by RANSAC => status=1
  for(i=0;i=object.size();i++){
  if(status[i])
  {
  }
  }
```